# Integer expression expected error for each loop in script

Tags: bash, unix

The following:

```
dest=$1
while read -r line
do
    num=$(grep -o "[0-9]" <<< "$line")
    if [ "$num" -gt 1 ]; then
        echo "$line" 
    fi
done < "$dest"
```

This is mean to print out the line with a leading digit greater than 1, but instead prints a random integer, with most cases stating integer expression expected.

The file being read in and looped over contains lines which all start with number, followed by a space and a sentence:

```
3 overflow-x
4 font-size
....etc
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong in the if statement? is there a way to convert the digit into an actual number type instead of doing string comparisons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you should seriously consider using this short & simple `awk` command instead of while loop, `grep` and if condition script:

```
awk '$1>1' file
3 overflow-x
4 font-size
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use anchor to match the number present at the start.

```
num=$(grep -o '^[0-9]\+' <<< "$line")
```